# python filter none values

Tags: django, django-views

I have:

**1. models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ROOT_CHOICES = (
        ('Manufacturing', 'Manufacturing'),
        ('Transportation', 'Transportation'),
        ('Installation', 'Installation'),
        ('Operation', 'Operation'),
    )
    root1 = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=ROOT_CHOICES, default='Manufacturing')
    root2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=ROOT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    root3 = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=ROOT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    root4 = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=ROOT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

**2. views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post=post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('data:post_detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form=CommentForm()
    template = 'data/post_detail.html'
    context = {'form':form,'post':post}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**3. html**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="post-parameters">
         <p class="text-parameters"> Root: {{ post.root1 }}, {{ post.root2 }}, {{ post.root3 }}, {{ post.root4 }}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

It looks like this, right now, in my html file: **Root:Manufacturing, None, None, None** which is correct. However I would like not to show the ,if any, None values e.g. **Root:Manufacturing**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) filter, so: `{{post.root1|default_if_none:""}}`

Alternatively, you can check for each value specifically

```
{% if post.root1 %} {{post.root1}} {% endif %}
```